# How to get the real data type of each column?

Tags: python, pandas

I know that `df.info()` (and other functions) give me the `dtype` of each column. However, pandas store a lot of things (e.g. String) as `object`, and I also see that some columns having `NAN`/`True`/`False` shown as `object` except as `boolean`.

How do I get the *real* data type of each column instead of a large bunch of `object`s?

BTW, this question is close to what I ask, but none of the answers helps:

[*Is there a way check if an object is actually a string to use .str accessor without running into AttributeError?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62523254/pandas-is-there-a-way-check-if-an-object-is-actually-a-string-to-use-str-acces)

Comment: Is this question what you are looking for? [Python pandas: how to obtain the datatypes of objects in a mixed-datatype column?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64195782/1609514)

Comment: I think the issue with the NAN/True/False is that there is not a single datatype in the column. NAN is not a bool, and so the column does not contain all values of a single data-type.

Comment: if your column has mixed datatypes, the datatype of that column is represented as an object datatype. Even if you are mixing `float` and `int` values in the same column, the resultant datatype will be an `object` datatype.

Comment: the *real* dtype *is* `object`. You are asking about the specific Python type. Generally, you use the `type` built-in for that, e.g `print(type(whatever)`, except here, you need to apply it to every item in your column

Comment: I had a similar question, and found that something like `df[f].dropna().map(lambda v: type(v).__name__).mode()[0]` gives me the most-common python type of non-null elements.  where `df[f].dtype` gives `object` the python type will give things like `str`, `Decimal`, `ndarray` etc

Comment: @patricksurry would you mind converting that comment into an answer? I think it's really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on my comment above, I've usually done something like below, as illustrated with an openml dataset.  It uses `type(v)` on each of the non-null values in the column and returns the most common value.  Possibly a choice other than mode would be better in some circumstances if you have strangely mixed data.

```py
from tabulate import tabulate
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml


def typename(v):
    return type(v).__name__


def best_python_type(col):
    non_null = col.dropna()
    return None if len(non_null) == 0 else non_null.map(typename).mode()[0]


df, _ = fetch_openml("titanic", version=1, as_frame=True, return_X_y=True, parser="pandas")

types = [
    dict(Column=name, dtype=col.dtype, pytype=best_python_type(col))
    for name, col in df.items()
]
print(tabulate(types, headers='keys'))
```

This results in:

```
Column     dtype     pytype
---------  --------  --------
pclass     int64     int
name       object    str
sex        category  str
age        float64   float
sibsp      int64     int
parch      int64     int
ticket     object    str
fare       float64   float
cabin      object    float
embarked   category  str
boat       object    float
body       float64   float
home.dest  object    str
```